# How to play CSS3 transitions in a loop?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, transform

The following style is just an example of how to set transitions in CSS3. 
 Is there a pure CSS trick to make this play in loop?

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    transition:width 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition:width 0.1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition:width 0.1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -o-transition:width 0.1s; /* Opera */
    transition:width 0.1s; /* Opera */
}

div:hover {
    width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

CSS transitions only animate from one set of styles to another; what you're looking for is [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_animations).

You need to define the animation keyframes and apply it to the element:

```
@keyframes changewidth {
  from {
    width: 100px;
  }

  to {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

div {
  animation-duration: 0.1s;
  animation-name: changewidth;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Check out the link above to figure out how to customize it to your liking, and you'll have to add browser prefixes.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to take advantage of the 60FPS smoothness that the "transform" property offers, you can combine the two:

```
@keyframes changewidth {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  to {
    transform: scaleX(2);
  }
}

div {
  animation-duration: 0.1s;
  animation-name: changewidth;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

More explanation on why transform offers smoother transitions here:
https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108