# CSS3 Transitions - making a box pulsate with different box-shadows

Tags: css, css-transitions

Ive read up quite a bit on this, but been struggling to get my head around it. I can find plenty of ways of animating the properties of a div on `:hover`, but I cant find anyway of just having properties animate without any user interaction.

Can someone show me how to get a div to pulsate, that is, animate the `box-shadow` property.

Something like

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #F00;
```

to

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00F;
```

Many thanks.

Comment: read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309673/css3-transitions-how-to-set-this-code-to-play-in-loop

Comment: Look up "CSS3 keyframes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via keyframes:

```
div{
    height: 100px;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
      -moz-animation-name: changeShadow;
      -webkit-animation-name: changeShadow;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
      -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeShadow{
  from {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #F00;
  }

  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00F;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes changeShadow{
  from {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #F00;
  }

  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00F;
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dc4f2/