# CSS3 infinite loop back to first image

Tags: html, css

I have a 5 image css3 infinite slider which is on a continuous loop (there is no jQuery or JS involved here and I don't want any either), however as soon as the last image has slid into position it jumps back to the first image. I have tried adding the first image as the 6th image in the group but this hasn't made any difference, can someone look over my CSS3 calculations to see what I'm doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
<figure>
        <img src="banner01.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="banner02.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="banner03.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="banner04.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="banner05.jpg" alt="">

</figure>
</div>
```

CSS3

```
@keyframes slidr {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; width:710px; height:300px; float:center; margin:auto; }
div#slider figure img {float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidr; 
  transition:.7s;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As soon as your animation reachesd `100%` it will repeat and snap back to `0%` - try to create a gap that allows the `-400%` to stay on screen longer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309673/how-to-play-css3-transitions-in-a-loop

Comment: @somethinghere thanks, I have just created a gap and it now works perfectly.

Comment: @somethinghere - You will need to write your answer as a reply not a comment so I can mark as answer

Comment: @html5css3 I have done so at your request :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `100%` part of the animation - the `-400%` value - is actually only being displayed for exactly... 0 seconds before it gets rewound to the 0% value. Try adding a gap that keep the `-400%` value active for longer:

```css
@keyframes slidr {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  20% { left: 0%; }
  25% { left: -100%; }
  45% { left: -100%; }
  50% { left: -200%; }
  70% { left: -200%; }
  75% { left: -300%; }
  85% { left: -300%; }
  90% { left: -400%; }
  100% { left: -400%; }
}

/* Sorry, I'm on Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes slidr {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  20% { left: 0%; }
  25% { left: -100%; }
  45% { left: -100%; }
  50% { left: -200%; }
  70% { left: -200%; }
  75% { left: -300%; }
  85% { left: -300%; }
  90% { left: -400%; }
  100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { 
  margin: 0; 
} 
div#slider { 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width:710px; 
  height:300px; 
  /* I dont think this is actually a thing: */
  float:center; 
  margin:auto; 
}
div#slider figure img {
    float: left;
}
div#slider figure { 
  position: absolute;
  height:100%;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  /* And again, I'm on Safari. Also, speed it up for development purposes. */
  -webkit-animation: 10s slidr infinite; 
  animation: 10s slidr infinite; 
  transition:.7s;
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
<figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">

</figure>
</div>
```

Notice that it actually *snaps* back to 0 and not animates. You could create a transition again - if you want to - by adding another gap that restores the left value to `0%`.

#### Update to return to start

To return to start, just make sure that:

- The total of different steps equals the amount of `frames + 1`
- The last and first step start at `0`

In SASS we could easily automate this process:

```
@mixin keyframes-slider($name, $frames){
    // Create keyframes wrapper
    @keyframes #{$name} {
        // Loop through the amount of frames (-1)
        @for $i from 0 through ($frames - 1) {
            // Divide the 100% by the amount of frames
            // The first frame is 0, and the last will return to 0
            #{100% / $frames * $i} { left: -100% * $i; }
        }
        // Add the final frame
        100% { left: 0; }
    }
}
```

Simply use it by including it and it will generate the keyframes you want:

```
@include keyframes-slider(slidr, 8);
```

As an example (pre-generated with 8):

```css
/* Thos following is my compressed SASS output. */
@-webkit-keyframes slidr{0%{left:0%}12.5%{left:-100%}25%{left:-200%}37.5%{left:-300%}50%{left:-400%}62.5%{left:-500%}75%{left:-600%}87.5%{left:-700%}100%{left:0}}@keyframes slidr{0%{left:0%}12.5%{left:-100%}25%{left:-200%}37.5%{left:-300%}50%{left:-400%}62.5%{left:-500%}75%{left:-600%}87.5%{left:-700%}100%{left:0}}

/* This is a quick way to give a good example. */
ul {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-animation: slidr 10s infinite;
  animation: slidr 10s infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
div, li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #ececec;
}
li:nth-child(2n){
  background: #dd0300;
}
div {
  position: relative;
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @somethinghere, I know it's bad manners to hijack someone's post but in your comment you state that you can animate it back to slide one. How would you do that? I'd love to use this but no idea how to do it!?

Comment: @Kungfauxn00b I have updated the post with information on how to rewind the loop as well as SASS implementation - which would have some more of the logic componenets so you can see how this is accomplished. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @somethinghere! I've got mine to "rewind" now (using CSS not SASS cause I don't really know what that is! (yet)) but is there any way for it to go from 8 to 1 without rewinding so that the slider appears infinite?

Comment: @KungFauxN00b SASS is a precompiler for CSS, allowing you to do logic like the above without repeating yourself to much (sass-lang.com, see also: LESS), while outputting regular CSS. An infinite spinner is impossible unless you use my previous code and repeat the first item in your gallery as the last (so you don't notice it snapping back to the beginning). Because it is only DOM manipulation, you can't make the first element appear to be _after_ the last element, so you need to repeat it. Does that help?