# css transitions not working while loop

Tags: php, html, css

On my site i have a list of tables that set a bunch of training for athletes on specific dates.

I want to add the ability to input how they did. I would like it to work in a way so that when you hover or click on the training a div would scroll down showing what was achieved.

I currently have the following code in the while loop:

```
    $sessTable .= '<table border = "1px solid black" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse">
                        <tr>
                           <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#E8E8E8 ">' .$newDate. '' .$attendBtn. '</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td><div style=" float:left" >' .$session. '</div>' .$editBtns. '</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="diary">
                            testing the div theory.<br/>
                            to see if it<br/>
                            will slide up and down

                    </div>';
```

The CSS

```
.diary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: height 2s;
  font-size:0px;
}

.diary:hover {
  height: 300px;
  font-size:12px;
  background:#CCC
}
```

It seemed to work fine when i tried it on a single div but when i put it in the while loop the hover works fine but seems to ignore the initial `.diary` state and also just jumps straight to the hover state with no transition.

My question is is this possible for multiple divs or is there a better way to achieve what i need.

Comment: This may help you. Check link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309673/how-to-play-css3-transitions-in-a-loop

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `transition` only for `height`

```css
.diary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: height 2s,background 2s;;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: height 2s,background 2s;;
  font-size: 0px;overflow:hidden
}
.diary:hover {
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #CCC
}
```

```html
<div class="diary">
  testing the div theory.
  <br/>to see if it
  <br/>will slide up and down
</div>
```