# How to suppress line break in div hover popup

Tags: html, css

I am now learning HTML to develop a help system for databases that I have developed. I am just at the stage where I'm trying to find code snippets that accomplish what I need and copying and pasting that code. I just started this two weeks ago so go easy, please -- I'm aware that the code may be messy and I'm open to any help with that as well.

I'm running into some problems with the functionality of a couple of things:

1. I'm getting an unwanted line break before a div tag.
2. If I include the rest of the text inside the div tag, the text looks different.
3. I would like for the popup to slide the text down and then back up.  (Is this possible?)

This is all for HTML Help Workshop so it seems that there are some limitations there.

Thank in advance for your help.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft&reg; HTML Help Workshop 4.1">
    <Title>Property Detail Report</Title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <h1>Property Detail Report</h1>
  <p>The Property Detail Report displays all data for a given property in one report. This combines key code information, lock inventory information and key inventory information in one concise report.</p>
  <p>This report is access three ways with three different results from the Property Report with three different results:</p>
  <a name="Show All Records"></a> 
  <p><img src="showallbtn.png" alt="Show All Records" Title="Show All Records" border="0"></p>
  <p>The "Show All Records" button will display all records for the current property in one report.</p>
  <a name="Search By Core"></a> 
  <p><img src="searchbycorebtn.png" alt="Search by Core" Title="Search by Core" border="0"></p>
  <p>  The "Search by Core" button allows you to narrow the scope of the records displayed to one core series or one core mark.  This button will bring up a  <a href="#"> <div class="hover-img">dialog <span> <img src="coresearchparameter.png" alt="parameter" /> </span>  </a> asking for the core mark that you wish to search for.  More information can be found in the <a href="propertyrpt.htm"> Property Report Help Topic, </p> </div> 

<OBJECT id=hhctrl type="application/x-oleobject"
        classid="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11"
        codebase="hhctrl.ocx#Version=6,1,7600,16385"
        width=100
        height=100
>
    <PARAM name="Command" value="Related Topics">
    <PARAM name="Button" value="Text:Related Topics">
    <PARAM name="Item1" value="Property Form Help;propertyfrm.htm">
    <PARAM name="Item2" value="Key Code Report Help;keycoderpt.htm">
    <PARAM name="Item3" value="Property Detail Report Help;propdetailrpt.htm">
    <PARAM name="Item4" value="Search by Core Detail Report Help;#search by core">
    <PARAM name="Item5" value="Search by Building/Structure Detail Report Help;buildingdetailrpt.htm">
    <PARAM name="Item6" value="Key Inventory Report Help;keyinventoryrpt.htm">
</OBJECT>
<OBJECT
   id=sample 
   type="application/x-oleobject" 
   classid="clsid:52a2aaae-085d-4187-97ea-8c30db990436"
>
<PARAM name="Command" value="HH Version">
</OBJECT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: "arial",arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: "arial",arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
  font-family: "arial",arial, sans-serif;
} 

a .hover-img { 
  position:relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }

a .hover-img span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position:absolute; left:-9999px; 
  top:-9999px; 
  z-index:9999; 
 }

a:hover .hover-img span { 
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 20px; 
  left:0;
}
```

Here is my output at the moment:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

The div tag should be easy to fix, add `display: inline;` to its section in the CSS. A good lesson to learn here would be how the `display` tag works, you can find a lot of good examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

As far as I can see, the reason why anything would look different if you include it in a div is because all divs in your HTML are wrapped in `<a> </a>`tags. That makes them into links, which underlines and makes them blue.

If you want to slide the text back up I would look into CSS transitions and keyframes. Maybe something in this thread would be useful for you: [How to play CSS3 transitions in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309673/how-to-play-css3-transitions-in-a-loop)