# JQuery loop text animation?

Tags: css

I can't get my text animation to loop for my assignment. It has been created using CSS, JQuery and HTMl respectively and runs perfectly but I have been trying and failing to put it on a continuous loop,
 my code is as follows:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.fly-in').removeClass('hidden');
  }, 700);
});
```

```css
#fly-in {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

fly-in li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif, helvetica;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 2.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, -.005, 0.32, 1.75);
}

.fly-in.hidden li {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fly-in.hidden li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(150px) translateY(-170px);
}

.fly-in.hidden li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-210px) translateY(170px);
}

.fly-in.hidden li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-100px);
}

.fly-in.hidden li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(-20px);
}

.fly-in.hidden li:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translateX(-70px) translateY(-200px);
}

.fly-in.hidden li:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translateX(200px) translateY(70px);
}

.fly-in.hidden li:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translateX(30px) translateY(200px);
}

.fly-in.hidden li:nth-child(8) {
  transform: translateX(30px) translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="fly-in hidden card-title">
  <li>K</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>T</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>S</li>
</ul>
```

The animation works but I can't get it to loop
Sorry if this question is confusing btw I'm very new to coding!

Comment: Just add `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` in `fly-in li` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play CSS3 transitions in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309673/how-to-play-css3-transitions-in-a-loop)

Comment: You know that you have `#fly-in`, `fly-in`, and `.fly-in`, right?

Comment: Use a snippet - fix your CSS selectors - don't add as much tags as possible, stick to relevant ones